# Unable to open files returned by os.listdir

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, file-io, operating-system

I have some code like this:

```
import os
directory = 'H:\\path\\to\\files'
for file in os.listdir( directory ):
  open( os.path.join( directory, file ) )
```

In a very small number of cases, running this code on a directory will throw the following error.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\path\\to\\files\\blahblah.file'
```

This doesn't happen for every file in the directory - the first few are opened correctly, but then it will fail on one of the files, the same each time.

The files in question *do* exist, so it's a problem with `open` rather than with `os.listdir`.

Strangely, changing the working directory and changing `directory` to be the corresponding relative path makes a difference to which file we fail on.

I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 10.

**Update** It seems to be connected to the length of the file names. The file names are very long in general: if I rename the file to something shorter, then it succeeds; longer and it fails again. That might explain why we were failing at different points when using a longer relative path.

Comment: Why are you running python 2.7? It's not supported anymore.

Comment: @MaxNoe My organization hasn't migrated to Python 3 yet.

Comment: perhaps it might have something to do with permissions

Comment: Indeed. Is it possible on windows that you can see that a file exists but you do not have permission to open it?

Comment: @AntonCurmanschii It's a good idea, but there don't seem to be any issues with the permissions. The file has no permissions restrictions on it.

Comment: And you are sure no other process is creating/removing files in the directory your are interested in?

Comment: @MaxNoe Yes, there's definitely nothing else touching those files.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to have been caused by the 260-character [path length limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd). The files that were failing had paths over 260 characters long.